# Systemctl status always shows full log, even with --lines

Tags: kali-linux, raspberry-pi, systemctl

I'm trying to get the status of a unit, but only the first 3 lines like this:

```
systemctl --user status resilio-sync --lines=3
```

I've tried various variations of this with -n 3 etc..., nothing works.
And the strange part: it always shows the full log (13 lines), instead of 10 lines which should be the default according to the documentation for [systemctl](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html).

Trying `systemctl status` confirms this: it just outputs all 45 lines to the terminal, when it actually should be 10.

Am I missing something here? As far as I know I didn't change anything.

As a workaround I'm currently using:

```
systemctl --user status resilio-sync | sed -ne '1,3p'
```

but I'd rather like to fix the underlying problem and use the native command.
System is Kali Linux (re4son-kernel, sticky fingers) on a Raspberry Pi (easy to blame on this strange setup, but since this is core Linux functionality I don't think it should matter)

[image: Output of the first command]

Comment: Welcome , Please add the output of the first command.

Comment: added it as a picture as I don't have the other machine connected to the internet atm.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The command `systemctl status` display the status of the service and the corresponding lines from `journalctl`, the `--lines=3` will limit the displayed number of lines from the journal to 3. e,g:

```
systemctl --user status resilio-sync --lines=0
```

will display only the status of `esilio-sync` service without the `journalctl` log.

> -n, --lines=
>
> When used with **status**, controls **the number of journal lines** to show, counting from the most recent ones. Takes a positive integer argument, or **0 to disable journal output**. Defaults to 10.

To limit the output of the `systemctl status` command you can use options:

```
systemctl check resilio-sync
systemctl is-active resilio-sync
systemctl is-enabled resilio-sync
```

or by groupping the options:

```
systemctl is-active is-enabled resilio-sync
```

Comment: ohhh the --lines argument only affects the journal part. I misunderstood the doc in that regard. Allright, that explains it, seems like I have to use `head` or `sed`

Answer (score 4):

This is what the head command was designed for.

```
systemctl --user status resilio-sync | head -n 3
```